# How to control / prevent the <Select> dropdown from setting the new option in angular-ui /angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui

I am using angular ui and have a drop down like this:

```
<select id="vehicleSelectDropdown"
        name="vehicles" 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control"
        ng-options="vehicle.name for vehicle in vehicles"
        ng-change="onVehicleSelected(this)"
        ng-model="selectedVehicle" required>
    <option value="" selected>Select Vehicle</option>
</select>
```

When I select an option, I will validate whether the user had made some changes, if the user has made some changes on the UI, then I prompt the user with a confirm modal dialog and decide whether I continue with the  option change or not.

The problem is that by the time the confirm dialog box comes up, the selection option is already changed.

How can I get this behavior:
- User selects an option
- Program does the validation and decides whether it is fine to go ahead with the new option or not
- Only if the program decides to go ahead with the new selection the Select option should be changed

Is this possible without any hack?

Comment: Use [$asyncValidators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators)

Comment: Couldn't you prompt a "wrong validation" and after the user closes the prompt, change the value back?